# Delete Rows in excel sheet using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have to delete the row if two column values are same. If Column B and Column D Values are same Then I have to delete that row. I am using one method but it is taking so much of time. Is there any other way to do it

Comment: I am using this method But it taking to much of execution time. Dim i As Long
For i = lngLstRow To 1 Step -1
    If Range("B" & i).Value = Range("D" & i).Value Then
    Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete

Comment: No code in comments. Please [edit] your question with the code.

Comment: I have added in the comments sections. please have a look on that

Comment: Sorry, what is misleading about "no code in comments"?

Comment: I tried few times , there is a code formatting error so I added in the comments. Would you dont mind that and help me in finding the solution?

Comment: Use a helper column: `=B1=D1`. Filter on `TRUE` then delete all the visible rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be faster to delete all the rows in one go rather than delete them one by one. Save the ranges that should be deleted and then delete them all at the end.

To add the ranges together you will want to use Union(Range1,Range2) but that will give an error if one of the ranges is nothing. So for the first row, you need to just Set and not Union(). See below:

```
    Dim i As Long, rDel As Range
    For i = lngLstRow To 1 Step -1
        If Range("B" & i).Value = Range("D" & i).Value Then
            If rDel Is Nothing Then
                Set rDel = Rows(i).EntireRow
            Else
                Set rDel = Union(rDel, Rows(i).EntireRow)
            End If
    Next i
    rDel.Delete
```